# How can I align a Point Cloud precisely

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a Point Cloud (with 20 Points). In this Point Cloud I connected two vertices (in Edit mode) with one edge. Now I would like to align/rotate that edge (and the Point Cloud with it) to one axis (e.g. y-axis). So this edge would need to be exactly on the y-axis (no rotation). I can zero out one vertice of this edge to the the origin. But I struggle to understand how I could bring the second vertice onto the y-axis. Any help would be great.

Update: I would need the edge to be parallel to the y-axis.

This looks promising:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Precise_Align

[image: This is what I would like to achive]

Comment: Do you mean that when you move that vertex the entire point cloud follows? Does the edge between the two vertices need to be same length or do you simply want to move the vertex along the shortest path from where it is onto the specified axis? Is it a one-time transform or does it need to be animated?

Comment: That addon indeed looks promising. If it does work, post it as an answer. Otherwise, I can do the math to align the edge with one axis (but I don't believe I can do the python to apply that math within Blender). And if one vertex of the edge is at the global origin, making the edge parallel to a global axis will also, by necessity, make it actually on that axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an addon, [Mesh Align Plus](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/Mesh_Align_Plus), for strange situations just like this! In GIF form:

[image: Aligning a point cloud]

You can connect two of the points to form an edge if you like, it doesn't matter. You can also just move the point data (the mesh) by itself if you want to leave the object origin where it is. Check the demo video on the wiki (or ask here and I can include info for that).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the effort ! Will try it. This post was over a year old, i will accept it with your reply.